# Empty page before title

Tags: titles, books, blank-page

I would like to add a full-page sized image before the title. However, when using the code below an empty page appears after the image and before the title. If I change the document class to `article`, the empty page does not occur. How to remove this extra page in `book` class?

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Title}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{example-image}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the page numbering for `book` requires a recto (odd) page for all titles (including those for parts and chapters). `article` has no such restrictions since it typically doesn't deal with double-sided printing that has recto and verso pages. The easiest way to circumvent that in your situation is to place the image on "page 0" rather than "page 1" by adding `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` (or setting it verbatim `\setcounter{page}{0}`).

```
\documentclass{book}

\title{Title}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{page}{-1}% To ensure the title is set on an odd page
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{example-image}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I tried this, viewing via `evince`, I got strange output regarding the placement of the image on top of the title. removing the `fitpaper=true` option to the `\includepdf` cured that.